# How to easily extract features from a list of lists (or pandas.Series of lists)?

Tags: python, list, pandas, feature-extraction

**The problem**

I have the following pandas series in python:

```
df.Categories
```

That outputs:

```
01                   Crime, Reality-TV
02               Game-Show, Reality-TV
03                          Reality-TV
```

Which can be thought as a series of lists:

```
01                   [Crime, Reality-TV]
02               [Game-Show, Reality-TV]
03                          [Reality-TV]
```

**What I wish to do**

I'd like to somehow extract features from this like:

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

Where the first column indicates the "Crime" category, the second column indicates the "Game-Show" category and the third column indicates the "Reality-TV" category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use get_dummies assuming the column to be the one without lists

```
new_df = df['Categories'].str.get_dummies(', ') 

    Crime   Game-Show   Reality-TV
0   1       0           1
1   0       1           1
2   0       0           1
```

We are using [series.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) here. It Splits each string in the Series by sep and returns a frame of dummy/indicator variables. It conveniently provides a separator parameter for the strings, default being '|'.

Comment: OOooo I never knew this existed! Very convenient.

Comment: great answer +1, including little explanation and doc reference would make it better.

Comment: I knew get_dummies, but never looked up the doc to know that useful parameter.